# Order rows of result set except for one row in Redshift

Tags: sql-order-by, amazon-redshift

I need to order the result set from the select statement with union all as order by for the 1st select statement separate and the union all statement separate.

Here is a sample query as my requirement.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempa 
(
  value   INT
);

INSERT INTO tempa
(
  value
)
SELECT 1;

INSERT INTO tempa
(
  value
)
SELECT 2;

INSERT INTO tempa
(
  value
)
SELECT 4;



SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM tempa ORDER BY 1)
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS value ORDER BY 1;
```

Here the result is shown as

```
1
2
3
4
```

I need the result set to be ordered by as follows:

```
1
2
4
3
```

The row with value 3 is unioned at the end so I would like that value to be ordered by separately from the prior statement.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may introduce a computed column into your union query:

```
SELECT value
FROM
(
    SELECT value, 1 AS posititon FROM tempa
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 2
) t
ORDER BY position, value;
```